# How to auto-reply to reply-to email address sent from a forwarding email address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, email-filter, auto-reply

I'm using a third party application that automatically forwards email notifications to me when a user makes a post.

The emails are from `noreply@thirdpartyapp.com` but have the specific user's email address in the `reply-to:` field.

I have created a rule in Outlook using a template that auto-replies to emails from `noreply@thirdpartyapp.com` but instead of replying to the user's email address it replies to the noreply address and fails.

**Is there a way to configure Outlook or gmail to auto-reply to the 'reply-to' email address instead of the noreply address I'm using to filter?**

Comment: I would write an add-on to handle this behavior

Comment: @Ramhound Are you referring to an 'Add-In' in Outlook? How complicated would that be to do?

Comment: Would take me 20 minutes tops, but I am a experienced programmer, so not the best person to estimate something like that.